# Function doesn't work, have i sintax fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, nav

Well, i put my JS file which contains the code what has the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.menu-toggler').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $('.top-nav').toggleClass('open');
});

$('.top-nav .nav-link').on('click', function () {
    $('.menu-toggler').removeClass('open');
    $('.top-nav').removeClass('open');
});

$('nav a[href*="#"]').on('click', function () {
    $('html, body').animate( keyframes: {
        scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100
    }, options:2000);
});
```

});

The first two work nice, but the third doesn't. Indeed, my console shows this error:

```
',' expected. ts(1005) [13, 43]

',' expected. ts(1005) [15, 19]
```

So, where is the mistake? Thanks!

Comment: Don't post images of code or error messages -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `options:2000` 2000 options? What's that?

Comment: [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Comment: You've got the wrong format for the `.animate` arguments - review the examples on the link provided above by @Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method syntax is:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Where

- `properties` is a plain object of CSS properties and values that the animation will move toward.
- and `duration` is of type number or string determining how long the animation will run.

So, just update your code like:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - 100
}, 2000);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks, but is weird... I watched a video in which the code i put above runs in fact ( whit the _keyframes_ and _options_ words). I have to focus on it to understund 100%.

Comment: I am not sure about that, but this is the basic syntax for it which works always.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a comma instead of a colon in line 13